# ASP.NET Enabled Cors but still getting cors error in Chrome when Accessing API using Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

So in my WebApiConfig.cs I have the following code:

```
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            // Web API routes ASDC AS
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
                .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use http.get() method in Angular like so:

```
var Path = window.location.host;

console.log(Path + '/api/GetCars');

    $scope.Cars = [];

    $scope.GetCars = function () {
        $http.get(Path + '/api/GetCars').then(function (response) {
            $scope.Cars = response;
        })
    }
```

I get the following error from Chrome:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:50153/api/GetCars' from origin 'http://localhost:50153' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

What gives? I enabled CORS on a global level after reading many Googling, but this isn't working.

Many thanks

Comment: use `var Path = window.location.origin` instead of `location.host`. that is all

Comment: Looks like the generated URI doesn't include `http://`, so maybe your CORS policy is unable to detect which protocol is being used on the request, so it gets rejected. I'd also recommend being very careful about the order in which you register various middleware in the `Register` method. If `config.EnableCors` is in the wrong spot, you'll run into problems too.